# How to convert this SQL to Laravel query builder code?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Here is my SQL:

```
select
  m.id,
  m.first_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(mt.name) membership_types
from
  members m
  left join expert_memberships em on em.member_id = m.id
  left join membership_types mt on mt.id = em.membership_type_id
group by
  m.id,
  m.first_name
```

Comment: In general, we encourage question authors to make a serious attempt on their problem before asking a question. We then also ask that a summary of the things that were tried are added to the question, so that readers can show what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This:

```
 $members = DB::table('members')
    ->leftJoin('expert_memberships', 'members.id', '=', 'expert_memberships.member_id')
    ->leftJoin('membership_types', 'membership_types.id', '=', 'expert_memberships.membership_type_id')
    ->select('members.id', 'members.first_name', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(membership_types.name) membership_types'))
    ->groupBy('members.id', 'members.first_name')
    ->get();
```

group_concat you have pass as DB::raw otherwise it will not work in select.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if you help people who have made no effort whatsoever on their question, you may be downvoted. This is because some readers do not want Stack Overflow to become a place where free work may be obtained (even if, to some degree, that is happening already).

Comment: you forgot "AS" inside GROUP CONCAT. Thanks, this is very close